# How do I edit the video length of an MP4?

Tags: hex, mp4, hex-editors

How do I change the video length of an MP4 through a hex editor?
I'm pretty sure its somewhere under the mvhd section of the hex content, but I'm not sure where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the video you were talking about (or alternative)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UxHQ7dW6M2s